# filter objects into separate layers by fill color in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, layers

I have over 100 objects of two types (paths, compound paths). I want to filter these objects into separate layers based on fill color.  Note, there are only three different fill colors being used in the entire art board.

Is this even possible? If not, are there any alternatives? Doing this manually would be long and grueling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator has some tools available already to select the same object based on X quality.

[image]

Note the shortcut seen is one I assigned to it.

So to filter the objects you can select one, select Same > Fill Color and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut them and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste them in place on a new layer.

Comment: I use Ctrl+F to paste in place

Comment: @WELZ Paste in place is far better in almost any situation. You never know what elements need to be in which order. Especially if you are working on a file that you didn't create. It's no problem at all to simply bring an element to the front quickly with the shift+ctrl+[ or ] keys.